# How to rearrange list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to rearrange a list. I've got for example a list with categories:

```
<ul class="category">
    <li class="cat1 active">cat1</li>
    <li class="cat2 active">cat2</li>
    <li class="cat3">cat3</li>
    <li class="cat4">cat4</li>
</ul>
```

and a list with subjects

```
<ul class="subjects">
    <li class="sub1">sub1</li>
    <li class="sub2">sub2</li>
    <li class="sub3">sub3</li>
    <li class="sub4">sub4</li>
    <li class="sub5">sub5</li>
    <li class="sub6">sub7</li>
    <li class="sub7">sub7</li>
    <li class="sub8">sub8</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is when a certain category has the class active, some subjects will go to the top of the list. for example like this:

```
<ul class="subjects">
    <li class="sub3">sub3</li>
    <li class="sub5">sub5</li>
    <li class="sub8">sub8</li>

    <li class="sub1">sub1</li>
    <li class="sub2">sub2</li>
    <li class="sub4">sub4</li>
    <li class="sub6">sub6</li>
    <li class="sub7">sub7</li>
</ul>
```

I can do this with this code:

```
if($('li.cat1').hasClass('active')){
    $('.sub3, .sub5, .sub8').insertBefore($('.subjects li:first-child'));
}
```

But then the real problem starts when multiple categories is active. I have done it like so:

```
if($('li.cat1').hasClass('active')){
    $('.sub3, .sub5, .sub8').insertBefore($('.subjects li:first-child'));
}

if($('li.cat2').hasClass('active')){
    $('.sub3, .sub4, .sub7').insertBefore($('.subjects li:first-child'));
}
```

The result is this:

```
<ul class="subjects">
    <li class="sub4">sub4</li>
    <li class="sub7">sub7</li>
    <li class="sub3">sub3</li>
    <li class="sub5">sub5</li>
    <li class="sub8">sub8</li>
    <li class="sub1">sub1</li>
    <li class="sub2">sub2</li>
    <li class="sub6">sub6</li>
</ul>
```

the order is now 4,7,3,5,8. Those are the numbers that have been selected but how do I rearrange them into: 3,4,5,7,8,1,2,6? Could someone help me with this? Here is the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NTPd4/2/

Comment: updated, with a little more info, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do 2 things to make it ALL good. First, make an sort method to suit your needs (i went by alpha of inner html, pik your poison). Second, make a variable for a jQuery object you can simply add elements too.

Next, use the variable in your if statements to gather the elements you want. Then before inserting, sort them!

## Example

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){  
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
};  

var activeSubjects = $();
if ($('li.cat1').hasClass('active')) {
    activeSubjects = activeSubjects.add($('.sub5, .sub3, .sub8'))
}

if ($('li.cat2').hasClass('active')) {
    activeSubjects = activeSubjects.add($('.sub3, .sub4, .sub7'))
}

activeSubjects.sort(sortAlpha).insertBefore($('.subjects li:first-child'));
```

I think the `.add` will sort them automigikally, but keep in mind, you could also use the sort function straightforward, like:

```
$('.sub5, .sub3, .sub8').sort(sortAlpha);
```

Also, for your current setup (where all text is same except for number) you could use a sort function like:

```
function sortNum(a,b) {
    return parseInt($(a).text().substring(3)) - parseInt($(b).text().substring(3));
}
```

However, the `sortAlpha` will probably better suite your needs in the long run.  As I mentioned before, you can arrange your sort function how you like.

Comment: Hey this works. I added a third one with `.sub1` in it but doesn't go to the top of the list?

Comment: well, thats because i made the function to "alpha sort", meaning its going by "sub" for right now, by i figured you would be applying real words. Like I said, you can rearrange that sort function all you like. Just remember, if your return is `+` then b is before a, if `-` then a is before b and if `=` then no sort is made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all five elements in their original order, you need to move them at the same time. Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) to combine them:

```
$('.sub3, .sub5, .sub8').add('.sub3, .sub4, .sub7').prependTo($('.subjects'));
```

Or, integrating it into your code:

```
var $selector = $();    
if ($('li.cat1').hasClass('active')) {
    $selector = $selector.add('.sub3, .sub5, .sub8');
}
if ($('li.cat2').hasClass('active')) {
    $selector = $selector.add('.sub3, .sub4, .sub7');
}
$selector.prependTo('.subjects');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GYfpv/

Comment: `.remove` in that is not necessary

Comment: that works a little bit, but only 3,4,7 will be rearranged. I want 4,7,3,5,8 to be rearranged because they have been selected by the category 1 and 2.

Comment: actually what I want to do is something like this `if ($('li.cat2') && $('li.cat1').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.sub3, .sub4, .sub7, .sub5, .sub8').prependTo($('.subjects'));
}`